# An extra empty row occured when I am using CASE WHEN expression in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to output some necessary rows for my report using a simple query to fetch. That's the query:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT Z.ITEMDESC, X.NMCODDES AS CODE

FROM NMCODMAS X, NMITEMAS Y, NMSALREC Z

WHERE 
       X.NMHRDCDE='PKZ'
       AND Y.FINISHGD='Y'
       AND X.COMPCODE=Z.COMPCODE
       AND Y.COMPCODE=Z.COMPCODE
       AND X.COMPCODE=Y.COMPCODE
       AND Y.USERDEF1=X.NMSOFCDE
       AND Y.ITEMCODE=Z.ITEMCODE
       AND Z.DOCTDATE BETWEEN NVL(:P11,Z.DOCTDATE) AND  NVL(:P12,Z.DOCTDATE)
```

[And Here's the ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcVqO.png)

But for some reasons I can't use `X.NMHRDCDE='PKZ'` IN WHERE. So, I just use `X.NMHRDCDE='PKZ'` in a CASE WHEN Expression. Just Like that:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT Z.ITEMDESC, 

CASE 
WHEN X.NMHRDCDE='PKZ'
THEN X.NMCODDES
END AS CODE

FROM NMCODMAS X, NMITEMAS Y, NMSALREC Z

WHERE 
      -- X.NMHRDCDE='PKZ'
       Y.FINISHGD='Y'
       AND X.COMPCODE=Z.COMPCODE
       AND Y.COMPCODE=Z.COMPCODE
       AND X.COMPCODE=Y.COMPCODE
       AND Y.USERDEF1=X.NMSOFCDE
       AND Y.ITEMCODE=Z.ITEMCODE
       AND Z.DOCTDATE BETWEEN NVL(:P11,Z.DOCTDATE) AND  NVL(:P12,Z.DOCTDATE)
```

In this case every row has been duplicated with an NULL  NMCODDES field. Check the output-[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCs0c.png)

I can't understand why there has been an extra empty row for every item. And using an `ELSE` in the above code doesn't make any difference. Because I can assure that in my DATABASE every item has an unique `NMHRDCDE`. SO, even using `ELSE` in the case will not solve my problem.

Could someone help me pinpointing the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to ignore that rows is:

```
select * from (/*YOUR QUERY*/) where code is not null;
```

As WJack wrote your nulls are ruturned when case not matches and it is correct behaviour. Where clause defines which rows will be returned, case defines what will be returned for rows. So your second query returns rows for any `X.NMHRDCDE` but do not have value for `X.NMHRDCDE != 'PKZ'`

Comment: Yes .. it worked. Many thanks. One thing more... could this format be used as nested ??

Comment: @W.Jack sorry but I don't understand. What do you mean by format? You mean nesting analutic function in other query or in other function?

Comment: No.. actually I mean using  ' select * from (/*YOUR QUERY*/) where code is not null; '  in another similar query as nested...

Comment: @W.Jack I gave you such solution because I was trying to make it the most similar to your original. If you need another query please specify why you can't use ` X.NMHRDCDE` on where and what are other limitations for where

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select a.ITEMDESC,b.CODE from
(SELECT DISTINCT Z.ITEMDESC 

FROM NMCODMAS X, NMITEMAS Y, NMSALREC Z

WHERE 
      -- X.NMHRDCDE='PKZ'
       Y.FINISHGD='Y'
       AND X.COMPCODE=Z.COMPCODE
       AND Y.COMPCODE=Z.COMPCODE
       AND X.COMPCODE=Y.COMPCODE
       AND Y.USERDEF1=X.NMSOFCDE
       AND Y.ITEMCODE=Z.ITEMCODE
       AND Z.DOCTDATE BETWEEN NVL(:P11,Z.DOCTDATE) AND  NVL(:P12,Z.DOCTDATE)) as a


LEFT JOIN

(SELECT DISTINCT Z.ITEMDESC, 

CASE 
WHEN X.NMHRDCDE='PKZ'
THEN X.NMCODDES
END AS CODE

FROM NMCODMAS X, NMITEMAS Y, NMSALREC Z

WHERE 
      -- X.NMHRDCDE='PKZ'
       Y.FINISHGD='Y'
       AND X.COMPCODE=Z.COMPCODE
       AND Y.COMPCODE=Z.COMPCODE
       AND X.COMPCODE=Y.COMPCODE
       AND Y.USERDEF1=X.NMSOFCDE
       AND Y.ITEMCODE=Z.ITEMCODE
       AND Z.DOCTDATE BETWEEN NVL(:P11,Z.DOCTDATE) AND  NVL(:P12,Z.DOCTDATE)) as b
on a.ITEMDESC = b.ITEMDESC
```

Comment: i forgot, it is work if you use code is not null, even though in second query only